# Add a custom manifest.json entry through Webpack Encore

Tags: webpack, webpack-encore

I want to map several asset names to the same asset file in the webpack `manifest.json`.

To demonstrate:

```
{
    ...
    "imageA.png": "image.png",
    "imageB.png": "image.png",
    "imageC.png": "image.png",
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this in the `webpack.config.js` file or similar?

Thanks